# How can I add a text in an API address with requests library (Python)

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary, python-requests

I want to add some texts into an API address in Python.
I am using `requests` library and the API address is:

> [https://one-api.ir/translate/?token={token}&action={action}&lang={lang}&q={query}](https://one-api.ir/translate/?token=%7Btoken%7D&action=%7Baction%7D&lang=%7Blang%7D&q=%7Bquery%7D)

I should insert **my token** in `{token}` and in `{action}` section I should put **google** search engine and in `{lang}` I should put the language that I want to translate to which is **fa** (persian) and in last section, `{query}` I should put my text that I want to translate.

this is my code:

```
response = requests.get('https://one-api.ir/translate/?token={token}&action={action}&lang={lang}&q={query}')

response.json()['result']
```

How can I get an input from user and replace them instead of `{token}`,`{action}`,`{lang}` and `{query}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at f-strings? f-strings are a way to format strings in python. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting

Example:

```py
token = "KeepThisSecret"
request = f"http://api.com/{token}/xyz"
print(request) # http://api.com/KeepThisSecret/xyz
```